# SQL Join fields from 3 tables

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have 3 tables of data that I need to join to make one table and show the following fields:
u.master_id, p.surname, p.forename1, c.number, u.status

Here are the table details:

```
Table 1 (person p)
Field name = entity_id (number)
Field name = surname(text)
Field name = forename1(text)
Field name = auditflag

Table 2 (users u)
Field name = master_id (number)
Field name = email (number)
Field name = status (text)
Field name = auditflag

Table 3 (contact c)
Field name = master_id (number)
Field name = entity_id (number)
Field name = number  (text = holds the actual email address)
Field name = auditflag
```

The master_id field from table 2 and 3 links to the person entity_id ( master_id=p.entity_id )

The email field from table 2 links to the entity_id in table 3 ( u.email=c.entity_id ) to get the number

The auditflag is used to mark each as an active record i.e. ( p.auditflag=1 AND u.auditflag=1 AND c.auditflag=1 )

I'm using Excel 2010 VBA - joining to a PostGreSQL database to get the data.
Below is the code I am using to join the 2 tables which works fine, but my problem is that "email" only shows a number because the actual address is in a 3rd table (Contact) under the field called "number".

I don't know how to include the 3rd table to show the field c.number in my query.

```
Const sqlconnection = "Provider=oledb;"

Dim conn As New Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = sqlconnection
    conn.Open

Dim rs As Recordset

Dim prs As String
    prs = "SELECT u.master_id, p.surname, p.forename1, u.email, u.status " _
    & "FROM users u INNER JOIN person p ON u.master_id=p.entity_id " _
    & "WHERE u.auditflag=1 AND p.auditflag=1 " _
    & "ORDER BY u.master_id "

Set rs = conn.Execute(prs)
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rs, Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .Refresh
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have all the pieces; all you need to do is add the third table to the query and select the columns you want.

```
Dim prs As String
    prs = "SELECT u.master_id, p.surname, p.forename1, c.number as email, u.status " _
        & "FROM users u INNER JOIN person p ON u.master_id=p.entity_id " _
        & "    INNER JOIN contact c ON c.master_id=p.entity_id and u.email=c.entity_id " _
        & "WHERE u.auditflag=1 AND p.auditflag=1 AND c.auditflag=1 " _
        & "ORDER BY u.master_id "
```

As written, this query will only get users that have active (`auditflag=1`) `person` rows *and* active `contact` rows.  Changing to left joins and moving the `auditflag` checks to the join condition would allow returning users without active rows in all three tables.

As a side note, I find the column names in your tables are actively working against easily understanding what they mean; if you can, I'd suggest re-thinking the names you're using.

Comment: Thank you. This really helps me understand how to tie things up better.